# Make replacements in a property of a json item using sed and jq

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq

I have a file with a list of json items (one per line), looking like this:

```
{ name: "Bob", location: "Boston, MA" }
{ name: "Peter", location: "San Francisco, CA" }
{ name: "Jane", location: "New York City, NY" }
```

Let's say, I would like to replace `MA` with `Massachussetts` in the location property. I know I could use `sed 's/MA/Massachussetts'` but this would also replace every `MA` in the `name` field.

Is there a way to do this from the command line, using `jq` for example?

Comment: Good to see that you're aware of `jq` already - have you given it a go?

Comment: I am very new to jq and very keen on learning to use it correctly

Comment: That `json` is not valid for several reasons. You should fix it if you want to parse it with `jq`.

Comment: Check it by yourself, for example, trying to parse it with `jq`, and how it complains about it.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be solved with `jq`. It's a tool I like, but as far as I know at current 1.4 version it does not have any function to substitute text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current public build of jq (1.4), there is no option to do regex replacements.  However that will change in the next version.

The [sub](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#subresubgsubresub) filter will alow you to do regex replacement on strings.  Then you could do something like this:

```
.location |= sub("MA$"; "Massachussetts")
```

Though, you'll have to do some creative manipulation to allow for multiple alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below.

```
$ sed 's/\(\blocation: \+"[^,]*, *\)MA"/\1Massachussetts"/g' file
{ name: "Bob", location: "Boston, Massachussetts" }
{ name: "Peter", location: "San Francisco, CA" }
{ name: "Jane", location: "New York City, NY" }
```

**OR**

```
$ sed 's/\(\blocation: \+"[^"]*\)\bMA/\1Massachussetts/g' file
{ name: "Bob", location: "Boston, Massachussetts" }
{ name: "Peter", location: "San Francisco, CA" }
{ name: "Jane", location: "New York City, NY" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which assumes your data is clean and the substitutions you need are limited.

```
.location = (
   {
     "Boston, MA":        "Boston, Massachussettts",
     "San Francisco, CA": "San Francisco, California",
     "New York City, NY": "New York City, New York"
   }[.location] // .location
)
```

if `filter.jq` contains the above filter and `input.json` contains

```
{ "name": "Bob", "location": "Boston, MA" }
{ "name": "Peter", "location": "San Francisco, CA" }
{ "name": "Jane", "location": "New York City, NY" }
{ "name": "Unknown", "location": "Unknown" }
```

then

```
jq -M -c -f filter.jq input.json
```

will produce

```
{"name":"Bob","location":"Boston, Massachussettts"}
{"name":"Peter","location":"San Francisco, California"}
{"name":"Jane","location":"New York City, New York"}
{"name":"Unknown","location":"Unknown"}
```

Note the use of `//` to leave location unchanged if the lookup failed.